# How to remove Custom Eventlog on uninstall?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

In my current assignment I am having a requirement where I need to create custom eventlog during installation and uninstall this custom eventlog during uninstallation.

I am able to create custom eventlog during installation, but I am not able delete it during uninstallation. I could not find any documentation on how to delete the custom eventlog.

Can somebody please let me know is it possible or not? If possible, please guide me on how to achieve it.

Comment: If you add a code snippet, it could be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to achieve this with [`<util:EventSource />`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_eventsource.htm) element. If that's the case, then the component hosting that event source should regulate its install / uninstall behavior.

If a component is scheduled for the installation, the event source will be created. If a component is to be uninstalled, it removes the event source altogether. At least, this is the way most elements work when placing inside the component.

If that's not the case, edit your question to add more details and some code, as I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am using <util:EventSource /> element. On the test machine if the UAC is on, then after uninstallation the custom event log is getting deleted. If the UAC is off then it is not getting deleted. Also what I observed is the custom log details are removed from windows registry, but the actual event file (in C:\windows\system32\winevt\logs\customlog.evtx) is not getting deleted. Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: It doesn't look like a correct behavior... What does the verbose log (`/l*v log.txt`) say?